# Entity Framework Core Data Annotation Database Generated Values

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-annotations, entity-framework-core

The Entity Framework Core documentation for [Generated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) makes it seem like Data Annotations can be used for generated code first ["timestamp"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-data-annotations) properties such as created/updated on as a `DateTime` type.

When trying to use the following data annotations along with code first migrations:

```
public class Foo {
    // some properties

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    // more properties
}
```

I receive the following error when attempting to execute command `dotnet ef migrations add AddFooTimestamp` in the command line:

> Identity value generation cannot be used for the property 'Created' on
>   entity type 'Foo' because the property type is 'DateTime'. Identity
>   value generation can only be used with signed integer properties.

Is there an effective way to utilize the data annotations described in the documentation in the models along with code first migrations in a EF Core and SQL Server environment? OR is it just `[Timestamp]` annotation that would be available at this time?

My project is using tool `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` version "1.0.0-preview2-final" and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` & `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` versions "1.1.0".

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try changing the Data Annotation to `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have to `DateTime` model properties that are set on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` actions I utilized a combination of [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values) via `Fluent API` configuration and database triggers. The annotations I mentioned in my question absolutely do not automatically configure SQL Server to generated default or updated `DateTime` values.

**Model:**

```
public class Foo {
    // some properties

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    // more properties
}
```

**Default Values:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .Property(i => i.Created)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .Property(i => i.LastUpdated)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
}
```

**Database AFTER UPDATE Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Foo_UPDATE] ON [dbo].[Foo]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 1) RETURN;

    DECLARE @Id INT

    SELECT @Id = INSERTED.Id
    FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE dbo.Foo
    SET LastUpdated = GETDATE()
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

Thanks!